# Gradle - Could not create an instance of Tooling API implementation

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, gradle-tooling-api

I'm trying to import a project from GitHub and build/run it on Android Studio. I am getting the following error:

> "Error:Could not create an instance of Tooling API implementation
>   using the specified Gradle distribution
>   'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.4-all.zip'."

I have tried the following:

1. Invalidate Cache and Restart
2. Changing the distributionURL in gradle-wrapper/properties to 2.5 etc.
3. Deleting build.gradle and restarting

These are ideas I got from several other posts on stackoverflow so I cannot explain why I tried these. (I'm very fairly new to Android Studio).

My `build.gradle` file looks like this:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.1'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    } }

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    } }

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir }
```

Comment: post the build.gradle files

Comment: I copied and pasted it. Thanks for your help

Comment: Use classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'. The 1.5.1 doesn't exist.

Answer (score 7):

I was facing a similar issue, updating the `Gradle` version in `distributionUrl` solved it.

`distributionUrl` field is present under this directory:

```
project-root-directory/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties
```

Answer (score 2):

Please, change

```
   distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.4-all.zip
```

with

```
    distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.8-all.zip
```

Then change

```
  classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.1'
```

with

```
 classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0-alpha3'
```

It should work.

Comment: This didn't work. Sorry I thought it had earlier. I downloaded Android Studio again, started a new project, and made your suggested changes. The first change is in gradle-wrapper.properties I guess, under the application folder. The second is in build.gradle. The new error is "Error:Could not create an instance of Tooling API implementation using the specified Gradle distribution 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.8-all.zip'."

Comment: change in `classpath` version of Gradle to `1.3.0` and stay with `gradle-2.4-all.zip` - if upgrading is not allowed try to downgrade to `1.3` version

Comment: Anyone have any solutions to this issue? I am too facing same issue while importing project into eclipse. I am using java 9

Answer (score 1):

For me I think it is permission issue. From Eclipse I have also faced the same issue. On my gradle installation path (i.e. /opt/gradle) I have make it chmod as 777. So that other tool can access the same. Run the following 2 commands -

```
cd /opt
sudo chmod 777 -R gradle
```

Comment: This did not work for me on a fresh installation of Studio 3.3 on Ubuntu.  Both /opt/android-studio/gradle and ~/AndroidStudioProjects/myproject/gradle were already owned by me with permissions 775, and when I chmod -R 777 both of them and restart studio I have the same issue.

Comment: +1 This was it! Thanks. But now I want to know in which user group `Intellij` itself falls. Why was `Intellij` being revoked access to `/opt/gradle`? In which user group does it normally belong?

Answer (score 0):

Java versions > 9 and Gradle versions >= 5.0.0 has some code breaking changes.  Here is to go around them using Eclipse.  It should be similar in AndroidStudio.

- Install the latest version of gradle from its distribution site 
  ("https://services.gradle.org/distributions/") and
  unzip the it on your PC.
- When importing the gradle project in eclipse select the option "local installation 
  directory" and point to the folder where you unzip gradle.
- (Bonus) if it is a LibGDX project, you need to also change the following in the Desktop 
  build file due to code breaking changes between gradle versions <5.0.0 and >=5.0.0. 
  Change "sourceSets.main.output.classesDir" to "sourceSets.main.output.classesDirs".

This is working for me and I am using LibGDX with Java 11 and Gradle 5.2.1 on Windows 10 while running Eclipse 2018-12.

Comment: Hi, (especially if you are building a LibGdx project), after following the above instructions, you may need to run your gradle builds to that it can build the necessary files for your project.  I usually import my project in android studio and use the gradle sync option.  However, you can run gradle wrapper of your project on the command line as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting the folder gradle-2.4-all in ~/.gradle/wrapper/dists